# RSP points not to the top of the stack?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, stack, gdb

I have a problem understanding how the stack works. First my little code:

```
void func1 ( int z ) {
  int i = 1;
}

int main ( ) {
  func1 ( 89 );
  return 0;
}
```

I am using: 
Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, 
gcc version 5.4.0, 
gdb version 7.11.1.

I was debugging with GDB, to see how the compiler pushes function arguments on the stack.

When I examine the stack at the point of the where RSP points, I get this:

```
(gdb) x/10xw $rsp
0x7fffffffdf20: 0xffffdf30  0x00007fff  0x00400525  0x00000000
0x7fffffffdf30: 0x00400530  0x00000000  0xf7a2e830  0x00007fff
0x7fffffffdf40: 0x00000000  0x00000000
```

When I print out the address of newest created variable, I get this:

```
(gdb) p &i
$4 = (int *) 0x7fffffffdf14
```

When I print out the address of the variable, which was hand over to the function, I get this:

```
(gdb) p &z
$5 = (int *) 0x7fffffffdf0c
```

The stack is growing to lower numbers.

So I thought that `RSP` always points to the top of the stack, meaning that when I i call this command `x/10xw $rsp` I am able to see all the variables from the function, but I can't see them from there.

The first address after this command is way higher than the address of the variable `z`. Because of that I was guessing that `RSP` points not on the top of the stack.

What is also wondering me, is that the address of `i` is higher than the address of `z`. 
Since `i` were later pushed to the stack than `z`, `i` must be a lower address than z in my opinion.

I hope someone can explain me why this is so.

**EDIT:** I have found the answer!
It was an optimization from the compiler. In `func1()` the `RSP` register had not pointed to the "top" of the stack because it was not necessary. It were just necessary if in `func1()` a other function were called. So the compiler saw that and didn't decrement the `RSP` register.

Here ismy assembler code with no function call in `func1()`:

```
   0x00000000004004d6 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x00000000004004d7 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x00000000004004de <+8>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi
   0x00000000004004e1 <+11>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
   0x00000000004004e8 <+18>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000004004f3 <+29>:    leave  
   0x00000000004004f4 <+30>:    ret
```

So you can see no `SUB` call for decrementing `RSP`.

Now the code from `func1()` with a function call:

```
   0x00000000004004d6 <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x00000000004004d7 <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x00000000004004da <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x20  
   0x00000000004004de <+8>:     mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi
   0x00000000004004e1 <+11>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
   0x00000000004004e8 <+18>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x00000000004004ed <+23>:    call   0x4004f5 <func2>
   0x00000000004004f2 <+28>:    nop
   0x00000000004004f3 <+29>:    leave  
   0x00000000004004f4 <+30>:    ret
```

So you can see the `SUB` call for decrementing `RSP`. So `RSP` can point to the "top".

Comment: The 64-bit call convention for Linux uses registers for the first six arguments. No stack involved.

Comment: in which registers will the values stored? you know a link or something were I can read about it?

Comment: This is a good thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64

Comment: thank you. but why i am then getting a address near RSP when I call p &i or p &z? Looks for me like they are on the stack

Comment: i is on the stack, naturally. I compiled and disassembled your code snippet, and gcc does copy the rdi register to a stack variable (using -O0). I wonder why. Maybe some default handling to preserve register values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where exactly is the red zone on x86-64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042188/where-exactly-is-the-red-zone-on-x86-64)

Comment: I saw in assembly code that first the argument was saved in EDI. BUt in the function it was then pushed on the stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention on x86 is that the stack grows "downwards" towards decreasing addresses.

The "top" of the stack is simply the location where something was *most recently pushed*; it's not based on the relative values of the addresses.  A stack can grow "upwards" or "downwards" in the address space - heck, for some implementations (such as a linked list), the addresses don't even have to be sequential.

[This page](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/04/where-the-top-of-the-stack-is-on-x86/) has a fair explanation with diagrams.

Comment: okay. that means that both of this are valid calls: mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x14],edi and mov    DWORD PTR [rbp+0x14],edi. ? But what happens if a new stackframe is created ? I thought the value of RSP were used as an orientation on which point unused addresses are aviable. Guess I still have to read a lot...

Comment: @FelixWe: Take a look at the page I linked to in my answer - it should help answer your questions.

Comment: I could answerd myself the question. The article pointed me in the right direction. I've added the answer to my question.