# Is there a way to calculate the bytes allocated to the stack frame of a function?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, stack-memory, stack-frame

I have been given this code in C and I need to calculate the bytes allocated to the stack frame of function arith. I looked everywhere for a way to do it but everyone has a different answer.

```
long arith(long x, long y, long z){
    long t1 = x + y;
    long t2 = z + t1;
    long t3 = x + 4;
    long t4 = y * 48;
    long t5 = t3 + t4;
    long rval = t2 * t5;
    return rval;
}
```

```
    arith:
    .LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        endbr64
        pushq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movq    %rdi, -56(%rbp)
        movq    %rsi, -64(%rbp)
        movq    %rdx, -72(%rbp)
        movq    -56(%rbp), %rdx
        movq    -64(%rbp), %rax
        addq    %rdx, %rax
        movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)
        movq    -72(%rbp), %rdx
        movq    -48(%rbp), %rax
        addq    %rdx, %rax
        movq    %rax, -40(%rbp)
        movq    -56(%rbp), %rax
        addq    $4, %rax
        movq    %rax, -32(%rbp)
        movq    -64(%rbp), %rdx
        movq    %rdx, %rax
        addq    %rax, %rax
        addq    %rdx, %rax
        salq    $4, %rax
        movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
        movq    -32(%rbp), %rdx
        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
        addq    %rdx, %rax
        movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
        movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
        imulq    -16(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

I tried to add up the bytes every time we call the datatype long so 6*8, which is 64 bytes but im not very sure about this.

Comment: If you can't judge what to do with the answers you already have, what will you do with  even more answers you may get here?

Comment: *At least* 6 longs plus a return address plus a base pointer.

Comment: I'm assuming the number of bytes that needs to be allocated on the stack depends on if you compile it optimized and if the function can be inlined.

Comment: The variables and parameters could be stored in registers and not require any stack space.

Comment: Using sane compile options - 0 bytes. No stack is used at all. Variables are not needed and will be optimized out. https://godbolt.org/z/3EcP4j1Kd

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: @Armali the answers I found were completely varied in calculations and results, but the replies cleared it up, thanks.

Comment: gcc has this option [-fstack-usage](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Static-Stack-Usage-Analysis.html#:~:text=A%20unit%20compiled%20with%20%2Dfstack,su%20extension.) Static Stack Usage Analysis that will generate an extra file that specifies the maximum amount of stack used, on a per-function basis.

Comment: Why would that function need stack space at all?  Stack space isn't needed for simple local variables.

Comment: @ErikEidt, this question was asked as a task in my lab report for assembly. I got stuck on it so I had to ask the experts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL:DR: no, you can't tell just from looking at the C.**
You need to look at the asm for a particular build and count `push`es as well as `sub $imm, %rsp`.

In this case, the variables aren't `volatile` so a normal build (with optimization enabled) would just use registers, not touching the stack pointer at all.  (You could say that the variables had their addresses optimized away, since they didn't escape the function, and nothing even took their addresses in the first place.)
See it yourself on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27long+arith(long+x,+long+y,+long+z)%7B%0A++++long+t1+%3D+x+%2B+y%3B%0A++++long+t2+%3D+z+%2B+t1%3B%0A++++long+t3+%3D+x+%2B+4%3B%0A++++long+t4+%3D+y+*+48%3B%0A++++long+t5+%3D+t3+%2B+t4%3B%0A++++long+rval+%3D+t2+*+t5%3B%0A++++return+rval%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cg132,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-fverbose-asm%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:33,endLineNumber:2,positionColumn:33,positionLineNumber:2,selectionStartColumn:33,selectionStartLineNumber:2,startColumn:33,startLineNumber:2),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) with GCC13 `-O3 -fverbose-asm`

```
 # first set of comments is compiler-generated, second are hand-written
arith:
        lea     rax, [rsi+rsi*2]  # t4,    # RAX = y*3
        sal     rax, 4    # tmp96,         # t4 = RAX = y*3*16 = y*48
        lea     rax, [rdi+4+rax]  # t5,    # t5 = RAX += x+4
        add     rdi, rsi  # t1, y          # t1 =  x + y  (replacing x in RDI)
        add     rdi, rdx  # t2, tmp102     # t2 =  x+y + z
        imul    rax, rdi        # rval, t2  # rval = t5 * t2
        ret
```

---

**If optimization is disabled** (*[Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point)*), **you can calculate a *minimum* from the `sizeof()` and `alignof()` for the named C variables** (assuming optimal packing), but compilers might reserve more for various reasons, like to align RSP, or

- *[Why does GCC allocate more space than necessary on the stack, beyond what's needed for alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009070/why-does-gcc-allocate-more-space-than-necessary-on-the-stack-beyond-whats-need)* - GCC missed-optimization bug; using less stack is essentially an optimization.
- *[Why is 0 moved to stack when using return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149806/why-is-0-moved-to-stack-when-using-return-value)* - clang with optimization disabled sometimes allocates extra space for a return value

In a leaf function in the x86-64 System V ABI, the compiler can just use the space already reserved (the red zone) for some/all of the space it needs, so it might appear that less is needed:

- [Why does the compiler reserve a little stack space but not the whole array size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523127/why-does-the-compiler-reserve-a-little-stack-space-but-not-the-whole-array-size)
- Or in Windows x64, there's 32 bytes of shadow space a compiler can use.  Some might choose to only use stack space for spilling incoming register args, not for other locals.