# Code generation for local stack variables in release vs. debug mode

Tags: assembly, x86, rust, code-generation, osdev

As part of my OS in Rust, I have the following system call entry point:

```
#[no_mangle]
#[naked]
#[inline(never)]
unsafe extern "C" fn syscall_handler() {

    // switch to the kernel stack dedicated for syscall handling, and save the user task's details
    asm!("swapgs; \
          mov gs:[0x8],  rsp; \
          mov gs:[0x10], rcx; \
          mov gs:[0x18], r11; \
          mov rsp, gs:[0x0];"
          : : : "memory" : "intel", "volatile");


    let (rax, rdi, rsi, rdx, r10, r8, r9): (u64, u64, u64, u64, u64, u64, u64); 
    asm!("" : "={rax}"(rax), "={rdi}"(rdi), "={rsi}"(rsi), "={rdx}"(rdx), "={r10}"(r10), "={r8}"(r8), "={r9}"(r9)  : : "memory" : "intel", "volatile");
    // do stuff with rax, rdi, rsi...
```

This works fine in debug mode, and in release mode (with debug info enabled) because it generates assembly code that stores the local stack variables like `rdi`, `rsi`, etc at negative offsets from the base pointer `rbp`. 
For example, here's the generated code:

```
<syscall_handler>:
swapgs 
mov    %rsp,%gs:0x8
mov    %rcx,%gs:0x10
mov    %r11,%gs:0x18
mov    %gs:0x0,%rsp
mov    %rax,-0x1f0(%rbp)
mov    %rdi,-0x1e8(%rbp)
mov    %rsi,-0x1e0(%rbp)
mov    %rdx,-0x1d8(%rbp)
mov    %r10,-0x1d0(%rbp)
mov    %r8,-0x1c8(%rbp)
mov    %r9,-0x1c0(%rbp)
movb   $0x4,-0x1b1(%rbp)
```

That code works fine, because my syscall handler runs with a stack pointer that points to the top of the current kernel stack (as usual), meaning that it's okay to use negative offsets from the stack pointer / base pointer (base pointer `rbp` is set before this based on the stack pointer value).

When I build in release mode without debug info, it generates code that uses positive offsets from the stack pointer itself (`rsp`, not the base pointer) as locations for the local stack variables. This is really weird and causes a problem because the memory above the current stack pointer `rsp` is out of bounds.

Here's the code generated in pure release mode without debug info:

```
<syscall_handler>:
swapgs 
mov    %rsp,%gs:0x8
mov    %rcx,%gs:0x10
mov    %r11,%gs:0x18
mov    %gs:0x0,%rsp
mov    %rax,0x1c0(%rsp)
mov    %rdi,0x1c8(%rsp)
 mov    %rsi,0x1d0(%rsp)
mov    %rdx,0x1d8(%rsp)
mov    %r10,0x1e0(%rsp)
mov    %r8,0x1e8(%rsp)
mov    %r9,0x1f0(%rsp)
```

Why is this code being generated, code that uses a positive offset from the stack pointer? That strikes me as very strange.

Is there any way to avoid that or change the code generation somehow?

Comment: Thanks. The red zone has been disabled in my target json file, so that's not an issue. To be clear, negative offsets from RSP are fine, positive offsets are the problem because the addresses above RSP are not mapped.

Comment: Negative offsets from RSP would only be fine if you *did* have a red zone.  But you don't, so they're not safe unless interrupts are disabled.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I am misunderstanding something. Say I have a kernel stack occupying addresses 0x4000 to 0x8000, with the top (`rsp`) being 0x8000. If i have a negative offset from the top of the stack, say -8, enough space for a u64, then the memory access will be valid at address 0x7FF8. If I have a positive offset, like shown in my code sample, the access would be invalid, no?

Comment: Right, it's also not safe to access stack memory you haven't reserved with `sub rsp, whatever`, or more generally that you don't own for some reason (e.g. red zone or function args on the stack).  In a normal function, you'd be scribbling over your caller's stack space.  In your case, you'd be referencing unallocated or non-stack memory, leaving all that stack memory below `rsp` (down to `0x4000`) unused.

Comment: The reason it's weird / confusing is that you asked for a `naked` function (thus no function prologue to reserve stack space), but then you used local variables inside it anyway.  I think in some C compilers that support naked functions, that's not supported; only inline asm as the entire function body is allowed.  But IDK what Rust says is officially supported as far as weird tangos between inline asm and the compiler.

Comment: Right, thanks for the clarification and for lending your expertise. Agreed on all counts, it's a bit strange to do it as a mixed assembly/Rust naked function, just something I wanted to try out. It's probably a bad idea to mix naked functions and local stack vars, as you said.

Comment: I added some of my previous comments into my answer.  You should probably mark it as accepted if you think it's a complete answer to your question.  Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks, will do. I'll post the Rust-specific code generation question on the Rust forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The stack grows down**.  Positive offsets from RSP are the part that's safe from async modification by interrupts, i.e. "reserved".

Negative offsets from RSP would be [the red zone, which you can't have on the kernel stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787408/why-cant-kernel-code-use-a-red-zone/38043511#38043511).

---

**Use `sub rsp, 0x100` or whatever to reserve enough space for your naked function's local variables.**  Or better, write the whole entry point in asm instead of messing around with compiler-generated code for this.

**Or better, just use `push` yourself, it's more compact (code-size) and just as efficient**.  `push` works very well for saving registers on the stack; Linux's system call entry points use that.  (e.g. [the entry point into an x86-64 kernel from `syscall` in 64-bit user-space](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e7d0c41ecc2e372a81741a30894f556afec24315/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S#L158) uses `push` to save all the registers, from Linux 4.12 (before the Spectre / Meltdown mitigation/workaround patches made the entry points more complicated).

---

The reason it's weird / confusing is that you asked for a `naked` function (thus no function prologue to reserve stack space), but then you used local variables inside it anyway.  Otherwise the compiler would `sub rsp, 0x...` on its own to reserve enough space for the locals before accessing them.

I think in some C / C++ compilers that support naked functions, that's not supported; only inline asm as the entire function body is allowed.  But IDK what Rust says is officially supported as far as weird tangos between inline asm and the compiler.  Like I said, you wouldn't have these problems if you wrote the entry point in pure asm.

---

Your debug-mode version appears broken; you're storing relative to RBP, but RBP hasn't been set yet.  You asked for a `naked` function, so you'd need to `mov rbp, rsp` yourself (after loading RSP from `gs:0`), and then `sub rsp, 0x20` or whatever to reserve enough space in the stack frame for those negative offsets.

I think your debug-mode version is storing relative to user-space's RBP, which will break horribly if user-space makes a system call with RBP pointing near anything that shouldn't be clobbered, and even more horribly if RBP holds a non-pointer value.

(If you had just been using `mov rbp, rsp` or something, as per your comment that you left this part out, then you were using space below RSP, which isn't safe without a red-zone.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, I previously considered just subtracting some space from rsp, or better yet set the initial syscall stack beneath the top of the stack itself, but that's kind of hacky in my opinion. 

Sorry, i had omitted some other code for brevity, but yes I am handling rbp properly. I guess my real confusion stems from it removing the frame pointer and then using positive offsets from `rsp`, which I did not expect (due to my own misunderstanding).